# Get full path of utility app like 7zip etc for shell command

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, shell, path

I like to call an external app like 7zip from my app with shell.

```
let res = shell(launchPath: "/path/7za", arguments: myargs)
```

The shell command needs the complete path to the app. With "ls" I know it. It is always "/bin", but what's about other additional commands or apps. You can install them wherever you want. How do I get this path?
Do I have to query the PATH variable and try every location? Sounds to complicated to me.
So how do I get the path neccessary for shell, if I know that the apps name is e.g. "7za"?

Shell function:

```
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String] = []) -> String
{
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments  = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    return output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the path of a program using the `which` command and it is usually located at `/usr/bin/which` on macOS

```
WHICH(1)                  BSD General Commands Manual                 WHICH(1)

NAME
     which -- locate a program file in the user's path

SYNOPSIS
     which [-as] program ...

DESCRIPTION
     The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run had these commands actu-
     ally been invoked.

     The following options are available:

     -a      List all instances of executables found (instead of just the first one of each).

     -s      No output, just return 0 if all of the executables are found, or 1 if some were not found.

     Some shells may provide a builtin which command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

SEE ALSO
     builtin(1), csh(1), find(1), locate(1), whereis(1)

HISTORY
     The which command first appeared in FreeBSD 2.1.

AUTHORS
     The which utility was originally written in Perl and was contributed by Wolfram Schneider <wosch@FreeBSD.org>.  The current version of
     which was rewritten in C by Daniel Papasian <dpapasia@andrew.cmu.edu>.

BSD                            December 13, 2006                           BSD
```

Alternatively you could just try the most common paths of 7za and do the `which` solution last if you can't find it

As @zwbetz pointed out, you can also use the `command -v` command which will also show you aliases.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I have searched for!

Comment: Just a small question:
let res4 = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/which", arguments: ["7za"])
let res5 = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/which", arguments: ["ls"])
The first one with 7za returns empty string, while second one returns "/bin/ls". In terminal both return the correct path. What's wrong?

Comment: Note: you can also use `command -v`. Example: `command -v 7za`

Comment: @Peter71 I'm not sure how you have your shell method setup but if 7za isn't in your PATH it won't find it

Comment: If I use "command" I get the same result. In terminal, "command -v 7za" delivers "/usr/local/bin/7za" which is fine. In XCode 10.1 Playground "let res = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/command", arguments: ["-v", "7za"])" returns empty string. For "ls" "command" is also returning correct path! I added the shell function in the main question.

Comment: Final approach: :-) I found a solution in Github using bash. See "Execute shell/bash commands from Swift · GitHub". It simply uses which to find command and executes it in bash. THis worked fine for me.